# MetaMask - RPC Error: The method personal_newAccount does not exist/is not available

Tags: web3js

When I execute following code then it show me: 
**MetaMask - RPC Error: The method personal_newAccount does not exist/is not available**

```
  if(typeof window.web3 !== "undefined" && typeof window.web3.currentProvider !== "undefined") {
            var web3 = window.web3 ? new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider) : new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/[infura-id]"));
           // web3.personal.newAccount('@!password').then(console.log);
            var password = "m'UxJjB][Tmk";
            //web3.accounts.create(password);
            web3.personal.newAccount(password,function (error, result) {
              console.log("In otherFunction with: " + result);
            });

          }
```

Comment: Add the following line in your code:

Comment: @goodvibration, 
which lines?

Comment: Which code?????

Comment: @goodvibration, I have edited my question and also add code. kindly review it

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask only support a limited set of Ethereum API, see here for the detailed list: https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/API_Reference/JSON_RPC_API.

The function personal.newAccount is not supported.